# Graphical display of multi-day calendar events?

Tags: solspace-calendar

Is there a way to graphically display multi-day events on a Solspace calendar? I am wanting to create a calendar that works like Google calendars so a multi day event displays as a color bar across the days of the event.

Just showing the title of the event on each day of the event doesn't cut it The graphical UI just communicates so much more effectively and quickly.

thanks!

Comment: For what it's worth... this seems like a CSS styling question since the calendar is showing the event on each calendar day.

Answer (score 1):

Anna is right, you can add custom classes for css to the event(s) using the {if event_multi_day}{/if} conditional.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that this is **very** difficult, since there are many elements to keep track of: how long is the "colored bar" compared to the table element, what if the event spans more than one week row?, how to align the bar to avoid making it look broken, what if there are multiple events overlapping, etc. Given this high complexity, we do not have a how-to solution available.

Comment: Instead of a how-to... how about a feature addition? I know a LOT of people would like to see such a feature and at $130 for an add-on it's the kind of development one would expect to see. I noticed that one of the sites in the Site Showcase section is no longer using Solspace Calendar and has gone to Google.

Current multi-day display is far too clunky to use so I too must use Google calendars instead.